# Gstreamer: How to set videomixer sink_0 caps in C

Tags: c, gstreamer

What I want to do is simple. Enable the sink pads on video mixer:

```
/* Manually link the mixer, which has "Request" pads */
mixer_sink_pad_template = gst_element_class_get_pad_template(GST_ELEMENT_GET_CLASS(videomixer), "sink_%u");
mixer_sink_pad = gst_element_request_pad(videomixer, mixer_sink_pad_template, NULL, NULL);
sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(videomixer, "src");
gst_pad_link(sink_pad, mixer_sink_pad);
```

And then set the alpha, xpos, ypos, e.g.

```
g_object_set(videomixer, "sink_0::alpha", 0.5, NULL);
```

But, that does not work.

```
(orig_code:22527): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class 'GstVideoMixer2' has no property named 'sink_0::alpha'
```

I'm trying to figure out the syntax for getting the C code to set videomixer's sink_0 & sink_1 pad properties.

Can someone point out how easy it is?

Comment: You cannot set the sink property via videomixer. Try `GstPad* sink_0 = gst_element_get_static_pad (videomixer, "sink_0");` then `g_object_set(sink_0, "alpha", 0.5, NULL);`

Comment: Thanks Martin. If I set the first one that way it appears to work, ie compiles and no run time warnings, but (in this case) the xpos is not changing. If I try to set the second it gives a warning or segfaults (depending on the presence of the first gst_element_get_static_pad). This makes me wonder if the code that requests the pads (shown above) is incorrect, as it is doing something similar. Suggestions are welcome. I'm going to dig into the request pads.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer to my own question.

First caveat. I think when bad data is fetched from the camera (usually at startup) there is not enough data to file the video stream and the code segfaults. My experience is: if you run again, it will be fine.

First things first. To gain access to the videomixer pads you have to create them when you link the elements. Here's an example:

```
  /* Manually link the mixer, which has "Request" pads */
  source0_src_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (source0, "src");
  mixer_sink_pad_template = gst_element_class_get_pad_template(GST_ELEMENT_GET_CLASS(videomixer), "sink_%u");
  mixer_sink_pad = gst_element_request_pad(videomixer, mixer_sink_pad_template, NULL, NULL);
  if (gst_pad_link(source0_src_pad, mixer_sink_pad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK) {
    g_printerr ("source0 and mixer pads could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return -1;
  }
```

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to set the xpos right after the auto-link:

```
g_object_set(mixer_sink_pad, "xpos", 1280, NULL);
gst_object_unref(source0_src_pad);
```

I'm setting the pads xpos later in the code with this code:

```
GstPad* sink_0 = gst_element_get_static_pad(videomixer, "sink_0");
g_object_set(sink_0, "xpos", 0, NULL);
```

Thanks to Martin for pointing me in the right direction.

Edited, because I misunderstood some code.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish something very similar.  I want to dynamically change the alpha value of videomixer.sink_1::alpha over time after the pipeline has begun running.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done that and I gave up on gstreamer. I'm coding everything myself now. It's much faster and I feel like I have control over everything.

Comment: When I get to it, I'm going to use the GPUs encoder directly from my C++. I'm still working on other issues at the moment.